# Почему происходит редирект при заходе на сайт? Как от него избавиться?

Tags: python, парсер, curl

По работе понадобился парсер страниц. Знаю, что уже есть много готовых решений, по типу того же Grab-a , но захотелось сделать свой костыль для практики.
Написал логирование на сайт и получение страницы, однако, оно работает несколько странно.

Код:

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
url = 'https://site.ru/index.php'
url1 = 'https://site.ru/index.php?_m=tickets&_a=manage&departmentid=17&ticketstatusid=1'


c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, 'username=user&password=pass&_ca=login')
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")

def __list(url) :
 c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.bodyio = StringIO()
 c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, c.bodyio.write)
 c.get_body = c.bodyio.getvalue
 c.perform()
 return c.get_body()

print __list(url1)
```

В итоге должен получать код тикетницы. Однако, после логирования в браузере происходит редирект. И код, в том виде, в каком он выше, отдает страницу редиректа. Однако, при комментировании части, отвечающей за логирование и создание куки, с использованием уже готовой куки отдает нужную страницу.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит и как от этого можно избавиться? 
Сам, если честно, вижу python впервые.

Comment: Что-то не понял вопроса, почему случается редирект? Потому что разработчики сайта так захотели. Как избавиться? Попросить разработчиков переделать сайт, чтоб работал без редиректов :) Или обрабатывать редиректы как положено в коде. Я с pycurl никогда не работал (зачем он нужен, если есть urllib и requests?), но беглый гуглинг говорит про `c.setopt(c.FOLLOWLOCATION, True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Перенаправление на [текущую] страницу это часто встречаемое поведение  при отправке веб-форм — это так называемая [Post/Redirect/Get модель](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get), чтобы избежать повторной отправки веб-формы при возможном обновлении страницы или при переходе по закладке.

Поведение когда метод меняется при перенаправлении с POST на GET было распространено в браузерах, но не соответствовало стандарту до [rfc 7231, которая узаконила это поведение](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.4). pycurl следует поведению браузеров, если [`CURL_REDIR_POST_*` опция](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTREDIR.html) не переопределяет поведение (имеет смысл только при включённом [`CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION`](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION.html)).

Чтобы зайти на сайт (чтобы получить cookies), а затем, имея cookies, запросить нужную страницу:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    # get cookies
    s.post(login_url, data=dict(username='user', password='pass', _ca='login')) 
    # use cookies
    html = s.get(ticket_url).content
```

Можно [явно передавать cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8977165/4279) или [сохранять/загружать их из файла](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25858635/4279).