# Не работает авторизация через pycurl

Tags: python, curl

Есть скрипт вида:

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO

c = pycurl.Curl()
url = 'https://site.ru/index.php'
url1 = 'https://site.ru/index.php?_m=tickets&_a=manage&departmentid=17&ticketstatusid=1'


c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, 'username=user&password=pass&_ca=login')
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")

def __list(url) :
 c = pycurl.Curl()
 c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.bodyio = StringIO()
 c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, c.bodyio.write)
 c.get_body = c.bodyio.getvalue
 c.perform()
 return c.get_body()

print __list(url1)
```

Ранее скрипт работал и, в принципе, выдавал ту страницу, что нужно.
Сейчас же, после обработки скрипта просто отдает страницу с авторизацией, а именно "https://site.ru/index.php" , не создает даже файлы в /tmp с cookie. В скрипте ничего не менял. Сколько не пытался понять - не могу выяснить причину, почему так происходит.

Comment: раньше [вы говорили, что этот код для вас не работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/765957/23044)

Comment: он был немножко подправлен. Добавилась строка c = pycurl.Curl() в функции __list , после этого стал работать отлично

Comment: где у вас `c.perform()` для первого `Curl()`? чтобы не путаться, уберите этот код в функцию и явно её вызывайте.

Comment: Большое спасибо, все получилось, как я, дурак, сразу не заметил.

Comment: от таких ошибок (как и мой пример показывает) никто не застрахован. Можно уменьшить вероятность ошибки придерживаясь лучших практик: избегайте глобальное состояние, тестируйте функции по отдельности и вместе (можно сперва вручную, позже для тестов можно свой простейший сервер с фиксированными ответами написать).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Благодаря подсказкам [jfs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs) код был приведен к виду:

```
import pycurl
from StringIO import StringIO


url = 'https://site.ru/index.php'
url1 = 'https://site.ru/index.php?_m=tickets&_a=manage&departmentid=17&ticketstatusid=1'

def __logging(url) :
 c = pycurl.Curl()
 c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
 c.setopt(pycurl.POSTFIELDS, 'username=user&password=pass&_ca=login')
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.perform()

def __list(url) :
 c = pycurl.Curl()
 c.setopt(pycurl.URL, url)
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEJAR, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.setopt(pycurl.COOKIEFILE, "/tmp/cookie.txt")
 c.bodyio = StringIO()
 c.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, c.bodyio.write)
 c.get_body = c.bodyio.getvalue
 c.perform()
 return c.get_body()

__logging(url)
print __list(url1)
```

Comment: от себя же поясню - при разработке скрипта отдельно тестилась часть с авторизацией. Соответственно, cookie уже была и использовалась старая. В данном же случае, при первом запуске она, логично, не создавалась, поэтому и работал он не так как нужно.